# How to add and save a new image with Gaussian noise

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, scikit-image, gaussian

In this bit of code, I am trying to add Gaussian noise to a PIL image and write it to an image file:

```
import os, skimage
from PIL import Image

images = os.listdir('/home/onur/Downloads/datasets/LFW-a/lfw2/')

for img in images:
    image = Image.open('/home/onur/Downloads/datasets/LFW-a/lfw2/' + img)
    image = skimage.util.random_noise(image, mode='gaussian', seed=None, clip=True)
```

I can't do `image.save()` because it is an `skimage.util.random_noise()` object. How can I write this to a new image file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had some trouble recreating your issue so I ended up using io from skimage to open the file. Assuming you want the result saved as an image in PIL format, try this.

```
import os, skimage
from PIL import Image

images = os.listdir('/home/onur/Downloads/datasets/LFW-a/lfw2/')
import numpy as np
from skimage import io

for img in images:
    image = io.imread('/home/onur/Downloads/datasets/LFW-a/lfw2/' + img)    
    image = skimage.util.random_noise(image, mode='gaussian', seed=None, clip=True)
    noise_img = np.array(255*image, dtype = 'uint8')
    pil_image=Image.fromarray(np.array(noise_img))
    pil_image.save('/Users/eric/Desktop/goproject4/test.jpg')
```

That being said, if you want to skip a few of these steps, you can open the file in a different way, or save it before converting the output to PIL